# Passing Data from Custom TableCell to ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom Cell class that holds a nameLabel and a gameLabel..

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *gameLabel;
```

These both are populated from a protocol on a separate view which the user fills out and hits done.  These then fill a TableView.

In order to populate the list on my tableview I have this

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PlayerCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];

Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
cell.gameLabel.text = player.game;

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbg.png"]];

 return cell;
}
```

My questions is I am then trying to get the nameLabel and gameLabel to segue into a UIViewController when the populated TableViewCELL is touched but I am getting a SigAbrt error. heres my code for the seperate segues.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPerson")] {
      UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
      PlayerDetailsViewController *playerDetailsViewController =[[navigationController viewControllers] obectAtIndex:0];
      playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
  } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewPerson"]) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      PlayerProfileViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
      dvc.personName = [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
```

players being my NSMutableArray and personName being my NSString that I have in my Destination View Controller along with the corresponding label.  and finally the sigabrt that I get with this comes from this code in my Destination View Controller

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   personLabel.text = personName; <-----WHERE THE SIGABRT TAKES ME
```

Any direction on where I am going wrong would be great I am still new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave personName the value of [players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in prepareForSegue. The class of that object is Player, not NSString, so you can't set a label's text with it. I suspect you want personName.name (and you should probably change the name to player or selectedPlayer if you want to pass a Player object, or pass just the name, rather than the Player object).

Comment: so in my destination controller it would be implemented as personName.name or in the prepare for segue..yeah still getting used to all these objects I am using and the naming structure

Comment: @Blake, Did you still have a question, or did my post answer your question?

Comment: got any suggestions on a good book or website that may have examples and tutorials..browsed through a lot but they seem outdated

Comment: @Blake, not really, I don't use tutorials or websites much. I did go through the Stanford course on iOS development, which I thought was really good. Mostly, I read Apple's documentation and do a lot of experimenting.